# Mounting a volume overwrites files stored in the Docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, lets-encrypt

I am trying to containerize the front-end of my website and automate its deployment. My goal is to be able to have a new image be generated and hosted when a change is pushed, and have the server automatically fetch it and restart the container. Here are the steps that I am taking:

1. I create the image by first building my Node application and then bundling the distribution and nginx configuration files into the latest [linuxserver/letsencrypt](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/letsencrypt/) image. This is the Dockerfile:

   ```
   # Use the NodeJS image as builder
   FROM node:alpine AS builder

   # Create the workspace
   RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
   WORKDIR /usr/src/app

   # Copy the package file and source code
   COPY package.json /usr/src/app
   COPY . ./

   # Install dependencies
   RUN npm install

   # Build the application
   RUN npm run build

   # The nginx server, this builds the final image
   FROM linuxserver/letsencrypt

   # Copy the nginx configuration
   COPY ./config/nginx.conf /config

   # Copy the output of the builder
   COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist /config/www

   # Inform Docker to listen on port 443 and 80
   EXPOSE 443 80
   ```
2. This image is uploaded to [GitHub's package registry](https://github.com/features/packages) and I poll for updates using [Watchtower](https://github.com/containrrr/watchtower).
3. The image is started using this docker-compose file:

   ```
   version: "3"
   services:
     ...
     frontend:
       image: [IMAGE]
       container_name: frontend
       cap_add:
         - NET_ADMIN
       environment:
         - PUID=1000
         - PGID=1000
         - TZ=[TIMEZONE]
         - URL=[URL]
         - SUBDOMAINS=www,
         - VALIDATION=http
       ports:
         - 443:443
         - 80:80
       volumes:
         - ./frontend:/config
       restart: unless-stopped
     ...
   ```

The issue is that the files that were packaged into the image using the `COPY` instruction are being overwritten when I use the following line in my docker-compose:

```
volumes:
  - ./frontend:/config
```

If I remove that section from my docker-compose file everything works fine, however this is not a solution because that folder stores important data.

I have read that mounting a volume completely overwrites any previous data, however I like the fact that I can easily load the image onto my server and have all the required files already embedded. Is there anything that I can do to fix my issue, or am I misusing/misunderstanding docker images?

I have tried setting the volume to read only as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534907/docker-compose-mount-volume-overwrites-host-files), however this did not work and instead caused the image to continually stop and restart.

I have also briefly read about [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) and am wondering if they will be of any use.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is expected. Docker mounts work in the same way as Linux mounts, i.e. overwriting contents of the target directory with the source directory contents.

My suggestion is to use another destination directory for your volume, e.g.

```
volumes:
 - ./frontend:/someotherdir
```

And then adjust your nginx configuration to look for JS files there.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I could retain the data in the image by first creating a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference):

```
volumes:
  frontend_data:
```

And then mounting the container to that volume:

```
services:
  frontend:
    ...
    volumes:
      - frontend_data:/config
    ...
```

Comment: This only works the very first time you start the container; if you update the config file in the image, the volume will not get updated.  (If you're thinking about deploying this on Kubernetes, this doesn't work there at all.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I have realized that I can copy files out of the container using the [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) utility. While I might be able to integrate this into my workflow, do you see this as an anti-pattern? More generally, would you recommend against embedding my data within the image?